# Workout using only dumbbells to burn fat and build muscles?

Tags: weight-loss, strength, muscle-mass, dumbbells

I have no time to go to the gym, my house is very small to buy large gym equipments and all I can buy is a set of dumbbells. I have only one hour per day to train. Currently I'm 79 KGs and I want to lose weight and build muscles. I don't wanna be a bodybuilder or something, but to have a great looking body, or in other words skinny-ripped.

Can you please recommend a set of exercises/workout using only dumbbells that train all of my muscles (and also allow me to gain muscles) so I can achieve my goal? Is this even possible without those large equipments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Muscle mass with dumbbells only](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18309/muscle-mass-with-dumbbells-only)

Comment: While this might seem off-topic, I will still advocate joining a gym, the key reason being ***for motivation purposes.*** You can certainly become ripped at home, but if you're like most people, your enthusiasm will dwindle with time. *There's no higher motivation for exercising in a gym when you see a small girl lifting higher weights than you are* *Or when you see people ripped than you, some ripped as you, and some worse than you.* And depending on where you live, you can find fantastic gyms whose 3 months subscription is lower than the cost of a single dumbbell :)

Comment: Those answers in the "duplicate" are junk and it's specifically about hypertrophy, which the question here specifically states *I don't wanna be a bodybuilder* .

Answer (score 3):

Regarding fat loss, I'll point you towards some info on how "[abs are made in the kitchen](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24495/is-weight-loss-possible-without-cardio/24500#24500)" (ie: diet is the biggest factor) and [strength training is superior to cardio for fat loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19117/7091).

You're not going to be able to use one of [the truly kick ass strength training programs](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091) because they are all about barbells, primarily because of the compound nature.

What I would actually recommend for you would be kettlebells. A good kettlebell workout will combine cardio and strength training, and specifically to your situation is cost effective and doesn't take a lot of space.

Get three: 16kg, 20kg, and 24kg. The brands worth buying are Dragon Door, Apollo, Life Line, and Ader. These three kettlebells will last you the rest of your life.

I would use an every-other-day approach, and do a routine that looks like the below. Aim for doing it for 30 minutes. Take 3 minutes before you do them all again. You'll start to pick an order that works for you (which ones before the other):

- [Two hand swings](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBTwoArmSwing.html) x25
- [Clean](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBClean.html) (once) and [press](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBPress.html) x10 (each side)
- [Snatch](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBSnatch.html) x15 (each side)
- [Single arm row](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/DBBentOverRow.html) x10 (each side... dumbell style)
- Pushups.
- [Turkish get-up](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBTurkishGetup.html) (x3 - x10 each side, depending on weight).
- [Planks](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/RectusAbdominis/BWFrontPlank.html). [Side planks](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Obliques/BWSidePlank.html).

Kettlebells can be brutal on your hands, use [chalk](http://amzn.to/1Fad7Rt).

Also, get a rubber mat of some type. I used a piece of full grain leather. You'll be dropping the kettlebell a lot (on purpose), like setting it down after two handed swings. There's not a lot of "gentle" ways to set 50lbs down when you're tired so whatever is under you will get beat up. I had a 3'x4' piece of full grain leather.

Comment: I agree with kettlebells, but I would not recommend an ab wheel to someone just starting out.  Without a strong core and shoulders, the ab wheel can create injuries.

Comment: @BackInShapeBuddy that's fair, didn't think about it. I'll edit it out.

Comment: +1 for kettlebells, though I'd advocate more cleans. Side presses, halos, and pass-through lunges are also good to have in complexes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have something you can use as a bench at your home, then there are plenty of workouts you can do with dumbbells to build muscle primarily but also burn some fat, too. Try to train each part 2-3 times a week, do under 16 repetitions, and do about 2-4 sets. (Some of the following you nay need an adjustable bench for) For your chest: Chest fly, incline chest fly, dumbbell bench press, incline dumbbell bench press, seated dumbbell chest press. For you biceps: Concentration curl, classic curl, straight arm standing curl, hammer curl. For your triceps: Tricep kickback, dumbbell tricep press. For your legs: Dumbbell front squat, calf raises w/dumbbell, dumbbell walking lunge. For your back: Dumbbell shrugs, Dumbbell rows. For your delts: Seated dumbbell shoulder press, decline flies, front raises, side lateral raises. There's also options for abs, but I personally believe that abdominal muscles are easier to be attained with a combination of calisthenics and cardio than weights, unless you are squatting/deadlifting(both w/barbell), which you are not. As for fat burn, I would say weights help but to really burn fat you have to run, bike, or swim. The last two are easier on your joints, I should note.

Comment: You voted to close this question as a duplicate, and then answered it?

Comment: @Eric Kaufman Just because I believe it to be a duplicate, does not mean I believe it to be a bad question.

Comment: @RobSterach - If you vote to close as a duplicate, then you are indicating you think the other question already provides suitable answers that cannot be improved.