# What workouts are for chest inflate at home

Tags: workout, chest

i would like to know how can i have an out chest.I know you will refer it to low,middle,up chest but i want to be specific.What i am searching is an exercise that brings my chest more out of my body.What exercise it could be helpful at home ?

Comment: Are you asking what would make it bigger as a whole?

Comment: no,you mean my chest to become big from left and the right side.What i mean,is to make my chest come out of my body more out.What i mean is if you look the body infront the chest should be more out.Not bigger i dont say about extended the size.I mean make it more comming out.Example when we say huge we mean to make it wider from left and the right.When i say inflate i mean as you see from infront the body i want to make the chest comming more front.Not extended from left or right i hope you get it

Comment: .It seems like this https://gr.pinterest.com/pin/469711436106797601/  . it is small but is inflate it

Comment: How old are you and how experienced are you with building muscles?

Comment: Back in the days been started with dumbells (even got question related to it https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18309/muscle-mass-with-dumbbells-only). You can do dumbells press just lying on the bench or even floor. It was not that bad in terms of effectives, I mean, for start

Comment: You cannot make your muscles wider... Building muscle always "**inflates**" the muscle.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate, however this is not the only build chest at home question. Search using the bar at the top, there are many questions about how to build the chest with little to no equipment.